# How to configure parse server to use an n-node mongo setup

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Migrating to mongo is well documented but I could not find a reference/guidelines for configuring the server to work with an n-node mongo cluster.

Mlabs suggest that if using anything other than single node (aka sandbox) users should run tests to cover primary node failure.

Has anyone configured parse server on let's say a 3-node mongo? How?

Alternatively, what volume of users/requests should prompt an n-node mongo cluster set up?

Answer (score 0):

use the uri you're given by the likes of mlab (mongo labs) - parse server will sort it out...